# Failing to build a C# program with xbuild in Linux

Tags: linux, mono, xbuild

I use Ubuntu and I'm triying to download a program that is supposed to be built and then run with mono but when i use `xbuild` it fails to build and returns some errors at the end of the output:

```
Done building project "/home/user/osu/osu-resources/osu.Game.Resources/osu.Game.Resources.csproj".
    Task "MSBuild" execution -- FAILED
    Done building target "Build" in project "/home/user/osu/osu.sln".-- FAILED
Done building project "/home/user/osu/osu.sln".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.

Warnings:

/home/user/osu/osu.sln:  warning : Don't know how to handle GlobalSection ExtensibilityGlobals, Ignoring.

Errors:

/home/user/osu/osu.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/user/osu/osu-framework/osu.Framework/osu.Framework.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

    /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets: error : Compiler crashed with code: 1.

     1 Warning(s)
     1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:14.1112530
```

Do you know what is causing this errorand how to solve it?

Comment: Set the verbosity to get details on the issue: `/verbosity:diagnostic`

Comment: @SushiHangover Is the last part of the return enough or should I paste the whole thing?

Comment: The idea of randomly downloading something and compile on Mono is just blind. Mono/xbuild is not for all projects clearly, and you should get back to the download link and confirm the vendor does support Mono as a platform. If you do intend to port some code base over, use latest Mono (which ships MSBuild and Roslyn) and that alone should rule out many incompatibilities.

Comment: It is meant to be compiled like this, I didn't just randomly do it, the vendor posted the download link next to a tutorial on how to compile it, it worked for most people